# Create a zip in specific Folder PHP

Tags: php, zip

I want create a zip in a specific Directory. Actually i can create a folder with this code:

```
function createZip($array)
{
    $files = $array;
    $zipname = 'ftpack.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    print_r($array);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $zip->addFile($file);
    }
    $zip->close();
}
```

But this code create a zip in the principal directory, i want create in the at /zipDownload directory.

Comment: Which of your variables does look like it contained the output filename? Prepend a pathname there.

Comment: Try with `$zipname = '/zipDownload/ftpack.zip';`

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the full path:

```
$zipname = '/path/to/ftpack.zip';
```

Also make sure that the folder `/path/to` is writable by PHP.